# right click on tab in google chrome, has stopped working

Tags: chrome

I think it was yesterday, the right click in a tab no longer does anything. However right click still works on a web-page.

I have several profiles, and have launched chrome in each, they all have this problem. I then logged in to the machine as a different user, and it works fine.

I suspect some configuration file is broken, but not the chrome profile. Is there a config file that I can delete?

---

- google-chrome: Version 81.0.4044.129 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- OS: Gnu/Linux, Debian 10.3, with kde plasma

Comment: I wish I had made a note of how I fixed this, and made an answer.